# Value not in index when subsetting dataframe

Tags: html, python-3.x, pandas, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble with a dataframe in Python.

I would like only those columns with a particular text ("Grado en"), but I get the error:

> Cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values when there are not NA's or NaN's.

If I use the option `na=False` it will return an empty dataframe. I have searched for a solution, but I can't find anything.

Here's my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import pandas as pd

list_of_titles_graus = []

html_graus = urlopen("https://www.universidadviu.es/grados-online") # Insert your URL to extract
bsObj_graus = BeautifulSoup(html_graus.read());

    for link in bsObj_graus.find_all('div'):
        list_of_titles_graus.append((link.span))


df_graus = pd.DataFrame({'title': list_of_titles_graus})

#Depuramos para que nos queden solo los titulos de los grados.

graudep = df_graus.dropna() #Eliminamos N/As
graudep = graudep.drop_duplicates() # Eliminamos duplicados.

#Check if there are NA or NaN
graudep.isnull().sum().sum()
graudep.isna().sum().sum()

#This gives me the error.
graudep = graudep[(graudep['title'].str.contains("Grado en"))]

KeyError: '[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan...] not in index'

#This doesn't do anything.
graudep = graudep[(graudep['title'].str.contains("Grado en", na=True))]

#This returns an empty dataframe.
graudep = graudep[(graudep['title'].str.contains("Grado en", na=False))]
```

My desired output is the following:

```
207  Grado en Psicología
221  Grado en Educación Primaria
233  Grado en Derecho
245  Grado en Traducción e Interpretación
257  Grado en Ingeniería Informática
269  Grado en Relaciones Internacionales
281  Grado en Trabajo Social
293  Grado en Administración y Dirección de E...
306  Grado en Educación Infantil
318  Grado en Criminología y Ciencias de la S...
330  Grado en Musicología
342  Grado en Economía
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This doesn't work for me... Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You are right. na=True return all rows

Answer (score 1):

This works with pandas 0.23.3:

```
(df_graus
  .assign(title = lambda d: d.title.apply(str)) # convert title elements from bs4 to string 
  .loc[lambda d: d.title.apply(lambda elt: "Grado en" in elt)] # filter in strings that contain "Grado en"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure there is no NA, then maybe try something like:

```
graudep.loc[graudep.title.apply(lambda elt: "Grado en" in elt)]
```

Comment: Ok I got it, `graudep.title` is not a string Series, it's a `bs4.element.Tag` Series.
Therefore:
    ```df_graus.assign(title = lambda d: d.title.apply(str)).loc[lambda d: d.title.apply(lambda elt: "Grado en" in elt)]```
Should do the work.

Comment: It worked! Can I bother you and ask you for a brief explanation of how it worked, please?

Comment: Also, How can I convert it to text in order to eliminate the <span> tags?

Comment: For a brief explanation see my indented commented reply.
To get rid of the tag use `.apply(lambda elt: BeautifulSoup(elt).text)` to the previous output.